# only uglify some JS files with Play Framework 2.x?

Tags: playframework-2.0, requirejs

Is it possible to force Play and its built in RequireJS to only uglify some files? I'd like to avoid compressing already compressed resources like JQuery and Lodash to speed up deploys to Heroku.

My only JS configuration is

```
requireJs += "main.js",
requireJsShim := "main.js"
```

in Build.scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we can't pass options to the optimizer directly, one option that comes to mind is mapping those resource to a CDN:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    "jquery": "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min"
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, using [fallbacks](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pathsfallbacks) doesn't seem possible.

Edit: You can do even better by using a different shim file.

**build.js**

requirejs.config({
     shim : ..., // your normal shim
     paths : {
       "jquery": "empty:"
     }
   });

**Build.scala** (or build.sbt)

```
requireJsShim := "build.js"
```